# In Scala, how to define a `val` in a `if block`?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My Scala codes looks like this

```
if (true) {
  val a = 1
}
else {
  val a = 2
}

print(a)
print(a+100)
```

the `print(a)` will throw an error because `a` is out of scope when evaluating that line.. Then how can I define a `val` according to a conditional expression? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `scala` `if` is expression - it returns value. So you could assign this value to `val`:

```
val a =
  if (true) {
    1
  } else {
    2
  }

// for simple expressions:
val a2 = if (true) 1 else 2

print(a)
print(a+100)
```

It's good to note that this idiom can also be extended to declaring and setting multiple variables by taking advantage of destructuring assignment:

```
val (a, b) =
  if (true) {
    (1, 5)
  } else {
    (2, 10)
  }

print(a)
print(b)
```

The above can further be extended to `match` statements and unpacking anything that can be `unapply`'d.

Additionally, if you have multiple variables of the same type, you can use list deconstruction:

```scala
val List(a, b) =
  if (true)
    List(1, 5)
  else
    List(2, 10)

// OR

val a :: b :: Nil =
  if (true)
    List(1, 5)
  else
    List(2, 10)

print(a)
print(b)
```

See also [Programming in Scala/Built-in Control Structures](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html#7.1)